# What HEVC codec tag to use with fMP4, hvc1 or hev1?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, hevc, fmp4

How does one choose the correct codec tag to use (`hvc1` or `hev1`) when muxing HEVC video into fragmented MP4 for streaming with MPEG-DASH/HLS?

I reckon there's a slight difference in muxing depending on the tag according to `ISO/IEC FDIS 14496-15`:

> When the sample entry name is 'hvc1', the default and mandatory value of array_completeness is 1 for arrays of all types of parameter sets, and 0 for all other arrays. When the sample entry name is 'hev1', the default value of array_completeness is 0 for all arrays.

Is there anything else apart from this?

Why are there two tags and what is the criteria to choose between the two?

Side note: Apple prefers `hvc1` according to their [HLS Authoring spec](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969487) for some reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'hvc1' stores all parameter sets inside the MP4 container below the sample description boxes.
'hev1' stores all parameter sets in band (inside the HEVC stream).

The parameter sets are essentially mandatory metadata necessary to decode the streams.

So you have two slightly different ways of muxing HEVC into MP4.

I'd choose based on the play out and transport scenario.

Your player or your transport specification may require one or the other.

Comment: I think `hev1` even supports both, in- and out-of-band parameter sets. See section `8.3.2` of `ISO/IEC FDIS 14496-15:2019(E)`.

Comment: Apple's QuickTime (Mac OS Big Sur) does not seem to be able to play back hev1, but hvc1 plays file

Comment: I wonder how the fact that many people switched to using MKV over MP4 changes this.

Comment: @jmsn No, on Apple devices, Mac, iPhone, iPad, it only supports hvc1 tag, for example, you can not use quick look on mac(by pressing space key) to preview hev1 tag video, you can send hev1 tag video from Mac to iPhone/iPad and save it in iPhone/iPad "Photos" app.

Of course, you can play hev1 tag video on macOS by using thirdparty player such IINA. but it's still not very convenient.